# Python list comprehensions misunderstanding

Tags: python, list-comprehension

There is seems to be something wrong with this example:

```
item = [x**2 if x %2 == 0 for x in range(10)]
```

But I can write like that:

```
item = [x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x**3 for x in range(10)]
```

Or:

```
item = [x**2 for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0]
```

How important is the order here and why I can't use 'if' without 'else' in the first example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different, unrelated uses of the `if` keyword here:

1. As part of a conditional expression, of the form `... if ... else ...`:

   ```
   item = [x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x**3 for x in range(10)]
   ```
2. As the filter for a list comprehension, of the form `if ...`:

   ```
   item = [x**2 for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0]
   ```

In your first example, you have a malformed conditional expression that is missing its `else`. Further, the semantics are different. In 1), you get some value in the list for *every* value in `range(10)`. In 2), you *only* get a value in the list for the even values.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because if you put the `if` in the first part, that defines the value, and the `if` is considered a ternary operator.

This means that you cannot have it without an else, just like you can't write

`item = 2 if other_item == 3`

Because the right side is evaluated to... what, when the other_item is not 3?

So, you need something like

`item = 2 if other_item == 3 else 4`

Your example is the same.

If you instead have it at the end, that's a conditional that excludes the value entirely, so you are not expected to have an alternative: you're basically saying "don't include this value in the results".

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.